# data structure is range or tuple

Tags: java, swift

I am trying to convert the following Java code into swift, but I do not know about this data structure `new (int start, int end)[input. length]`, any guidance would be appraciated.

```
public override void collection_entries(int[] input)
{    
   var ranges = new (int start, int end)[input.length];
}
```

Comment: For the record, the code in your question is NOT valid Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swift, you should use a `Range()`.

```
let start = 0
let end = 6
var ranges = Range(start...end)[input.count]
```